# Problem with List builder repeat the data when adding or removing item in the list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter. When I adding new item or removing an item from the list, the list builder does update the list, but the problem is that the list builder also displaying the previous item list and showing new updated item list. So what I want to do is keeping the new updated item list instead of old item list.

```
class AlarmPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String title;
      AlarmPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _AlarmPageState createState() => _AlarmPageState();
    }

    class _AlarmPageState extends State<AlarmPage> {
      String alarmName;
      // Test Function
      void _addAlarm() {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddAlarm()));
        });
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Provider.of<AlarmsProvider>(context, listen: false).getLocalStorage();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> allWidgetsAlarms = List<Widget>();

        return Consumer<AlarmsProvider>(builder: (context, alarmProviderItem, _) {
          List<String> localAlarms = alarmProviderItem.alarms;
          if (localAlarms != null) {
            localAlarms.forEach((item) {
              allWidgetsAlarms.add(
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Color(0xff212121),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // Alarm Name & Title
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                bottom: BorderSide(width: 2),
                              )),
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(Icons.alarm, color: Colors.yellow),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                                  Text('$item',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xffC1C1C1),
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            // Alarm Time & Toggle Switch
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'Time',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                                  Text(
                                    'AM / PM',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xffB5B5B5)),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 150),
                                  Icon(Icons.switch_camera, color: Colors.yellow),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            // Alarm Repeat
                            Container(
                              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Repeat',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 11, color: Color(0xff616161)),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: DaySelector(
                                    value: null,
                                    onChange: (value) {},
                                    color: Colors.yellow[400],
                                    mode: DaySelector.modeFull,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      onLongPress: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => AddAlarm(item: item)));
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 180),
                  ],
                ),
              );
              print(item);
            });
          }

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              title: Text('Azy Alarm'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/background_image(dark).png')),
              ),
              // child: ListView(children: allWidgetsAlarms),

              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: allWidgetsAlarms.length,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return allWidgetsAlarms[index];
                  }),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              elevation: 0,
              onPressed: _addAlarm,
            ),
          );
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your issue is this line: `allWidgetsAlarms.add(` You construct `allWidgetsAlarms` in your builder, but the builder is not called again every time you `Consumer` rebuilds, hence it is just appending the new contents to the end of the list. To fix this, keep your original initialization of `allWidgetsAlarms` just at the top of the builder in your Consumer, add the following line:

```
allWidgetsAlarms = List<Widget>();
```

This will resert `allWidgetsAlarms`. Hope it helps!